# styling a form button

Tags: css, forms, button

I would like to style a form button (input or button tag) with 2 background images to create a stretchable button (relative to the text-length). The form button should also have a hovered state and it should be cross browser (at least IE7 & +) would need to support it.

I know how to obtain the effect with just css with an  tag => test

If anyone could help me a little bit, I would be pleased

yours truthfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this link](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/update_styling_the_button_element_with_css_sliding_doors_now_with_image_spr/).

This will only work with `button` because an inner element like a `span`is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). They have a very easy cross-browser set of user interface controls that might satisfy your requirements. You can change the backgrounds used for the buttons, etc.